# OpenGL ES drawing dotted circular line circle

Tags: android, opengl-es

How to draw a circular line circle like this image?
How to achieve or any suggestions?

Not essential, but I'd like to draw it on Android.

[image: circular line circle]

Comment: I'd implement as a bunch of untextured quads positioned by CPU, and fired off in a single draw call. Each quad would be 4 vertices and 6 indices, using GL_TRIANGLES.

Comment: @Columbo nice approach! Do you have idea how to calculate the indices and vertices according to circular shape?

Comment: I´m guessing drawing the png quad won´t do it. What kind of "controls" do you want on the circle?

Comment: @Columbo May I ask how to fire one draw call contain many quads vertices?

Answer (score 0):

You can draw this by simply drawing colored rectangles. Either create a method to draw a rect and call it for each of the rectangles or create a buffer holding all the vertex data and call it once.

For the first procedure the easiest way is using matrices. Assume you are drawing a rectangle at `angle` of `height` and `width` with some inner circle `radius`. Now all you need is a single rect vertex buffer as:

```
{
    0.0, -0.5,
    0.0, 0.5,
    1.0, -0.5,
    1.0, 0.5
}
```

This represents a 1x1 cube which is positioned perfectly to draw a line. Now to use matrices we want to identity which would draw the line in the center of your screen. Then rotate it to whatever angle you need, then move it forward so it is outside of the inner circle and in the end scale it to whatever size you need:

```
Matrix4x4 matrix = Matrix4x4.identity // Start with identity
matrix = matrix.rotate(angle, 0, 0, 1) // Rotate around Z
matrix = matrix.translate(radius, 0, 0) // Translate it forward, this is not a bug
matrix = matrix.scale(height, width, 1.0) // Scale it
```

This should be it. Now if you want to add some performance on drawing you should have a single draw call so you create a single buffer. You may still use exactly the same procedure but transform original vertex data by a target matrix on CPU and then pack the result into array.

I am not sure from your image if the bottom (inner) part of lines needs to be circular. To achieve this the easiest way would be to draw to alpha mask first and then use it in blending. To achieve this you need to clear color to `(1,1,1,1)`. Then draw a circle only on alpha channel using color mask `(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)` and blending `(ONE, ONE)` then using a any transparent color like `(0,0,0,0)`. This will make your background completely white but there will be a circle in the middle with zero alpha.  So now reset back to default mask settings using `(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE)` and start drawing your rectangles with blending `(DST_ALPHA, ONSE_MINUS_DST_ALPHA)`. This should cut your rectangles nicely to show a correct circle in the middle.
Some more robust procedures exist for the same thing like drawing to stencil buffer instead of alpha channel.